# How do I switch back to default navigation bar appearance after unwind segue from custom nav bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, segue, detailsview

Have a question on segues and custom navigation appearances. Image 1 shows a search vc with navigation bar appearance set by my app delegate. As I search and segue to my detail vc, I have a custom navigation bar view in view did load (image 2). It's transparent. When i click back to the search vc, that custom appearance tags along as you can see in image 3. How do I revert back to the original nav bar appearance? I assume this is done in view will appear?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there's only one nav bar for all controllers in the navigation controller, so when you go back to the first controller you have to programmatically modify the appearance of the navigation bar to be the way it was before the segue; viewWillAppear is a good place to do so.